how to keep initial spaces for 1st field with awk
I have a file of that type:
   aaaaaa bbbb     cccccc
     dddddddddddddd ee  fff
  gggggggg hhh   iiiii

I want to ouptut only 1st & 3rd fields, but keeping the original spaces of 1st field, like:
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii

if I use simple print($1,$3), I get:
aaaaaa cccccc
dddddddddddddd fff
gggggggg iiiii

I have tried adding: $1=sprintf("%20s",$1)
--> but 1st field is aligned on its right side at the 20th column:
              aaaaaa cccccc
      dddddddddddddd fff
            gggggggg iiiii

thanks in advance for your (simple) proposal
PLP
i have tried using printf arguments, but I cannot output the exact number of spaces in front of 1st field

Using any POSIX awk:
$ awk '{x=$3; sub(/([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){2}$/,""); print $0, x}' file
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii

That saves the value of the 3rd field, removes the last 2 fields from the line, then prints what's left (i.e. the 1st field) followed by the saved value of the original 3rd field.
Alternatively with GNU awk for the 4th arg to split() so we can capture field separators as well as field contents:
$ awk '{split($0,f,FS,s); print s[0] f[1], f[3]}' file
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii

or also GNU awk for gensub():
$ awk '{print gensub(/(\s*\S+).*\s(\S+)/,"\\1 \\2",1)}' file
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii

but if you have GNU tools then you could also consider using GNU sed:
$ sed -E 's/(\s*\S+).*\s(\S+)/\1 \2/' file
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii


An approach using match to fill leading spaces. Works with the majority of awk flavors.
% awk '{if(match($0, /^ +/)){
    for(i=1;i<=RLENGTH;i++){printf("%s", " ") }}; print $1,$3}' file
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii

Data
% cat file
   aaaaaa bbbb     cccccc
     dddddddddddddd ee  fff
  gggggggg hhh   iiiii


FYI it'll work with all awk variants (except of course old, broken awk on SOlaris which should never be used nor considered)

@EdMorton Good to know! Had those older ones in mind. Didn't want to discriminate those who still might have to use them :). I only test with onetrueawk, nawk, gawk and mawk. Should be fine in general.

Anyone still using old, broken awk needs to get off it ASAP as it's, well, old and broken (see http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk) and it only still shows up on Solaris where there are other almost-POSIX awks also available (nawk and xpg awk), It's best just to forget it exists otherwise almost every answer we post would require an "if your awk supports it" caveat just to cater to it's unfortunate continued existence on Solaris.

If you just want something simple to get column 1 and 3 and furgetaboutit, you can use sed:
sed -E 's/^([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+).*[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+).*/\1 \2/' file

However, let's look at a more general solution than using fixed column selections. The easiest way to do this is to recognize that your fields are comprised this way:
[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+

Once you see that, you can use awk, sed, Perl, Ruby, etc to eliminated the unwanted fields and print the wanted fields.
Here is a ruby to do that:
ruby -lne '
BEGIN{wanted=[0,2]}
puts $_.scan(/\s*\S+/).select.with_index{|c,i| wanted.include?(i) }.join ' file

Or a GNU awk:
gawk -v FPAT="[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+" '
BEGIN{wanted[1]; wanted[3]}
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i in wanted) printf "%s%s", $i, i==NF ? ORS : ""}
' file 

Either prints:
   aaaaaa     cccccc
     dddddddddddddd  fff
  gggggggg   iiiii

Those two keep all existing spacing between the selected columns.
If you want to select which columns keep their leading spacing and which are trimmed and separated by OFS you can do:
ruby -lne '
BEGIN{wanted=[0]; wanted_trimmed=[2]}
puts $_.scan(/\s*\S+/).
    map.with_index{|c,i| 
        if wanted.include?(i) || wanted_trimmed.include?(i) then 
            c.sub!(/^\s*(\S+)/,"\\1") if wanted_trimmed.include?(i); c
        else
            ""
        end
}.reject(&:empty?).join($OFS.nil? ? " " : $OFS)' file

With Ruby or:
gawk -v FPAT="[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+" '
BEGIN{ wanted[1]; wanted_trimmed[3] }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        trimmed=$i
        sub(/^\s*/,"",trimmed)
        if ((i in wanted) || (i in wanted_trimmed)) 
            printf "%s%s", 
                (i in wanted_trimmed) ? trimmed : $i, i==NF ? ORS : OFS
    }
}
' file 

Either of those prints:
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii


Consider using [[:space:]]* instead of [[:space:]]+ as it's not clear if there are ALWAYS spaces at the start of the line or not.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
   aaaaaa bbbb     cccccc
     dddddddddddddd ee  fff
  gggggggg hhh   iiiii

then
awk '{match($0,/^ */);printf "%*s%s %s\n", RLENGTH, "", $1, $3}' file.txt

gives output
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii

Explanation: after using match RLENGTH value is number of leading spaces, then I use dynamic width to get such number of spaces by prefixing empty string with number of spaces to width of RLENGTH, then just put $1 and $3 into string sheared by space.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

With GNU Awk, you can define a field pattern using FPAT.
For example, defining a field as some whitespace followed by some word characters lets you directly print the first and third fields with their respective whitespace prepended:
awk -vFPAT='\\s+\\w+' '{print $1 $3}'

   aaaaaa     cccccc
     dddddddddddddd  fff
  gggggggg   iiiii

If you want to control the spacing yourself, you could define the field pattern as matching either spaces or word characters, then grab and print the first, second and sixth field, and a static string of spaces (or instead, just a comma, as the output field separator defaults to a space character):
awk -vFPAT='\\s+|\\w+' '{print $1 $2 " " $6}' # or {print $1 $2, $6}

   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii


You might want to use \S instead of \w as we don't know if the OPs non-spaces are entirely word-constituent characters or not. Also consider using \s* instead of \s+ as it's not clear if there are ALWAYS spaces at the start of the line or not.

We can use the match() function to find the location of $1 and then use substr() to piece together the 'new' line:
awk '
match($0,$1) { $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH) $3 }   # find $1; redefine $0 as start of line up to end of $1 (+1) and then append $3
1                                                      # print current line
' sample.dat

This generates:
   aaaaaa cccccc
     dddddddddddddd fff
  gggggggg iiiii


That would fail if $1 contained regexp metachars, you should use match($0,/[^[:space:]]+/) or similar (assuming the default FS value).
